# How do I retrieve a dictionary value by key in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am creating a game: Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock. The computer will prompt for a user choice and make one of its own. How can I display the value assigned to the dictionary key chosen by the computer?

```py
def play ():
    user = input("Choose 'r' for Rock, 'p' for Paper, 's' for Scissors, 'l' for Lizzard, 'm' for 'Mr.' Spock: ")
    #Key is abbriviation and the value is the name of the item chosen by the computer
    rpslm = {'r':'rock', 'p':'paper', 's':'scissors', 'l':'lizard', 'm':'Spock'}
    computer = random.choice(list(rpslm.keys()))
    
    choose = #want to display the value here so that the value can be displayed in the answers
    
    

    if user == computer:
        return f'Computer\'s choice was \'{choose}\'. It\'s a tie'
    
    #Scissors cuts Paper, Paper covers Rock, 
    #Rock crushes Lizard, Lizard poisons Spock, Spock smashes Scissors
    #Scissors decapitates Lizard, Lizard eats Paper, Paper disproves Spock,
    #Spock vaporizes Rock, and as it always has, Rock crushes Scissors
    
    if is_win(user, computer):
        return f'Computer\'s choice was \'{choose}\'. You Won!'
    
    return f'Computer\'s choice was \'{choose}\'. You lost'
```

Comment: So… you have a dict in one variable, and a key in another. You're asking us how to access the key (which you have in one variable) in the dict (which you have in another)…?

Comment: `choose = rpslm[computer]`. you should probably read a tutorial about the Python's basics: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Use the key chosen by the computer to access the value directly.

```py
# Bonus: dict.keys() returns a list; there is no need to convert it to a list again
computer = random.choice(rpslm.keys())

# Dictionary values can be accessed using the key as follows...
choose = rpslm[computer]
```